# Some classes are not scraped in Python web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

http://finance.daum.net/item/main.daum?code=052400

** This is a Korean finance web portal, which shows stock information for a Korean company named "Kona i"

I'm a beginner, just started learning web scraping with Python.
I was trying to scrape the price of this stock using BS. In the web page, the tag and the class of the stock price was em, "curPrice up" respectively. So I put "em.curPrice up" in the selector part. And when I printed it, only to come up with an empty list. What is the problem with it?

```
price = requests.get("http://finance.daum.net/item/main.daum?code=052400")
html = bs(price.text, "lxml")
current_price = html.select("em.curPrice up")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Well I tried it and recognized that the type is a list. So I tried "current_price[0].text" (without the quotation marks of course) and I got this error saying that the list is out of range. What should I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

The element you're looking for in the html appears to be this.

```
<em class="curPrice up">19,450</em>
```

An html selector of `em.curPrice up` will match an `<em>` with a class of curPrice, then find a child element `<up>`

You should modify the selector to `em.curPrice.up`